# How to edit remote files on an Apache server with Android application

Tags: android, apache

I need my app to be able to go to a specified URL and access a file, then insert text at a specific line of said file.  Is this at all possible?  I greatly appreciate your help and responses,  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just configure mod_dav so you get put support on the apache side. Then use a GET to pull down the file, edit it locally, and use PUT to send it back. Obviously, this will not work well from a concurrency standpoint, but it's fine for the basic text editor type workflow.

Alternatively, you could write server side code to actually edit the file on the server side.

Comment: Thank you.  What could I use to edit the file locally, and what would an example of some server side code be?  I seriously appreciate the help.

Comment: These are very basic questions. You should probably learn some fundamentals before trying to jump into something as complex as this.

Comment: You could use PHP, there's a plethora of PHP tutorials out there on the web. As far as the android app, I'm assuming you're already programming such a thing so you could just use the string manipulation functions.

Comment: Also what Falmarri said. Tutorials are your friend.

Comment: I figured that is what I could do with the app side work; I am fairly well rounded with local programming.  But this is my first time dealing with server side programming.  I will be looking into PHP tutorials, thank you.